# SwiftUI - ScrollViewReader scroll to top including padding (anchor plus constant)

Tags: swiftui, nslayoutconstraint

I have a ScrollViewReader and the scrollTo method works.

```swift
proxy.scrollTo(target, anchor: .top)
```

The item which is scrolled to is completely aligned with the `.top`-Anchor.

[image]

Now I want to include the padding of 7px.
Is there a SwiftUI equivalent to the *NSLayoutAnchor* below or any other method to make the green overlay always align with the List-Element.

```swift
NSLayoutAnchor(equalTo:self.view.topAnchor constant:7)
```

Comment: Add `.padding` to row view and assign identifier (which will be used by proxy) to it. Or if it is only at the very top then add empty view with own identifier above rows and use it in proxy.

Comment: @Asperi The rows have a padding and an id!  Thats what confuses me...
Ahh okay that could be one solution/workaround! Thanks.